# ASP.net Boilerplate - scope

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have my JS as:

```
(function () {
    var controllerId = 'app.views.dashboard';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, [
        '$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;
        //About logic... 
        var param = $stateParams.dashboardName;
        vm.dashboardName = param; // not working

        console.log(param); //Works
        $scope.dashboardName = param; // not working
    }]);
})();
```

My view is defined as:

```html
div ng-controller="app.views.dashboard as vm">
<h1
    Dashboard Detail {dashboardName}
</h1
```

I am having problems getting this one to work, any ideas? My state param seems to be passing properly, however the param isn't populating the token for angular. Help :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be double curly braces? Like `{{dashboardName}}`. Also you are missing closing `>` for `h1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you should reference dashboardName as `{{vm.dashboardName}}`

Comment: Thanks@! wow its one of those mornings. I was struggling with this for about a few days, And FINALLY just noticed it as you answered this question. Appreciate pointing that out... right in front of me the whole time! ... argh, coffee hasn't kicked in yet.